# Http Error 500 with this htaccess rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-redirect

I would like to redirect any request from `http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/mytitle-1.html` to `http://www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/script.php?id=1&code=5`

I don't understand why the rule below doesn't work. I added it in a htaccess file in `folder2`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/mytitle-1.html$ /folder1/folder2/script.php?id=1&code=5 [L]
```

Comment: Do you really get a 505 error code? That one is not very common. Does your server support rewriting URLs at all? Maybe this is the problem. The rule seems to be ok.

Comment: Is `mod_rewrite` enabled?

Comment: yes I think it supports htaccess as returns print_r(apache_get_modules()) returns a list containing mod_rewrite

Comment: not 505 but 500 error code

Comment: what could it be as rule seems correct and mod_rewrite is enabled ?

Comment: Have a look at QSA (Query String Append). Any error in .htaccess generates a 500.

Comment: well it still doesnt work...still getting error 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this instead, in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !script\.php [NC]
RewriteRule  ^folder1/folder2/mytitle-1\.html/? /folder1/folder2/script.php?id=1&code=5 [L,NC]
```

#### OPTION:

If .htaccess file is at `/folder2`, replace the above *RewriteRule* with this one:

```
RewriteRule  ^mytitle-1\.html/? /folder1/folder2/script.php?id=1&code=5 [L,NC]
```

For permanent and visible redirection, replace [L,NC] with [R=301,L,NC]

Comment: @StephaneKouakou Well, what's the problem with my answer? The rule in your question doesn't work because it is in `/folder2`. In my answer there is an option for that case.

Comment: yes thx a lot for your reply! You're right I think the server may have some config issue. Problem is I cant access Apache error logs so I'm bit lost at what's wrong! +1! anyway

Comment: @StephaneKouakou Let me know if you need any modification in my answer as soon as you can find out what's the error. Meanwhile, try replacing [L,NC] with [R,L,NC] for testing, in order to **see** the substitution URL. That will help, I guess.